# Error adding docs to CouchDB

Tags: json, couchdb, schema, pouchdb

My local PouchDB docs won't replicate to my remote CouchDB.

The sync is happening, because the browser downloaded my design schema, so it's not a permissions issue. I think that my design schema doesn't match my documents, but I struggled to find the correct way to write the schema.

**Schema**

```
{
  "_id": "_design/schema",
  "_rev": "4-3d9a49ebffbbd6b7b146240879baa7e4",
  "validate_doc_update": "function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx, secObj){ if(userCtx.roles[0] !== 'admin'){throw({forbidden: 'operation forbidden'})} }",
  "views": {
    "by_module": {
      "map": "function(doc){ if(doc.type == 'note'){emit(doc.note);} }"
    }
  },
  "schema": {
    "title": "Contact details",
    "description": "A document containing a person's contact details.",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "name",
      "level"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "_id": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "_rev": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "application_access": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "home": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "home_email": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "jobtitle": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "level": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "mobile1": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "mobile2": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "modified": {
        "type": "number"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "work": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "work_email": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "_doc_id_rev": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Doc**

```
{
  "_id": "fcb52b3072e2038647b328c0a700147f",
  "_rev": "1518449239461",
  "application_access": "User",
  "home": "",
  "home_email": "",
  "jobtitle": "Exemplar",
  "level":  "Bronze",
  "mobile1": "0987654321",
  "mobile2": "",
  "modified": 1518449239461,
  "name": "Zachary Zumbeispiel",
  "work": "",
  "work_email": "",
  "_doc_id_rev": "1518449239460::1-ffd3c056614845ada4a68de4793710ac"
}
```

So the question is, does my doc conform to my schema? Or is my schema wrong?

The "schema" was on the CouchDB instance, and the doc was in PouchDB.

Comment: CouchDB doesn't have a schema. That's kind of the whole point of NoSQL.

Comment: so if I remove the schema it will work?

Comment: There is no schema in CouchDB. You can't remove that which does not exist. As for solving your problem, I have no idea. You haven't provided enough information (error messages, etc) to diagnose.

Comment: but you have fixed my problem - so if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it (there weren't any error messages to post, that was part of why I was baffled).

Comment: I didn't fix your problem, because I haven't done anything except explain that CouchDB doesn't have schemas.

Comment: well, my not understanding that was the problem :)

Comment: You said documents don't replicate... That sounds like a problem, not a misunderstanding. What makes you think they aren't replicating?

Comment: they are replicating now, because I removed the "document schema" and so it can sync & replicate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165153/discussion-between-yvonne-aburrow-and-flimzy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are replicating now, because I removed the "document schema" and so it can sync & replicate.

So the problem was that I had read somewhere that I needed to add a schema to CouchDB, so I created what I thought was a schema, and evidently the structure of the docs to be synced has to be the same, so the sync did not work because the structure of the docs did not match.

Hence @Flimzy 's explanation that the whole notion of a schema was bobbins meant that I removed the "schema", and voila, the PouchDB and CouchDB can now sync - and problem solved.

Comment: I meant design document. http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/index.html